# Propagating DNS records from a new IP

Tags: dns, propagation

I have a more specific DNS situation than it is usually asked, and have extinguished reading resources already. At this point I'm pretty desperate. Here is the scenario

- Get a computer with OLD IP (let's call it that) for a new domain. Set up for the first time its own ns1.mydomain and ns2.mydomain successfully. They had propagated and all was fine whether you entered mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com
- Fast forward a few months, and have to upgrade to new machine, with NEW IP. Soon, I will no longer have access to OLD IP machine. I make an exact copy (went over it many, many times) of the DNS configuration from the old machine on the new one, replacing OLD IP with NEW IP
- Since the old machine is still running, I change its DNS records to point to the new IP instead, because I figured it would help 'transfer the authoritative dns' to the new machine. Of course, I have no real grasp of how the authoritative dns is set, even with all my reading.

  What followed is that after a few hours (it has been more than a day already by now), typing mydomain.com points to the new IP, while typing www.mydomain.com will keep pointing to the same old one. On the domain.com.zone file, on both OLD IP and NEW IP computers, I have a record for www IN CNAME domain.com.

  Also, going to http://www.intodns.com will say "Looks like the A records (the GLUE) got from the parent zone check are different than the ones got from your nameservers".

  Doing a nslookup, will say that the authoritative answers can be found at my nameservers, but they still point to the OLD IP

  Finally, still after 24h, if I do a service named stop on the OLD IP computer and go to http://www.internetsupervision.com, it will fail finding the DNS for mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com. Yet, if I turn named service back on, it will find it again immediately.

  I believe my lack of understanding of the authoritative DNS is preventing me from making a new IP machine start broadcasting the new DNS records. As I've said, I still have access to the old machine, but only for a few more days.

  If anyone has any insight to help me in this case, I appreciate. I really don't know what to do any more and have nobody to turn to. Why is my new, updated DNS IP not propagating properly?

Comment: It would be of interest what the TTL of your DNS records are, and whether you remembered to increase the serial number of the records when you updated them to point to a new IP.

Comment: I did increase the serial number at first, but not being sure about that I reverted it. I will increase it again. All the expiration info is: 3600 refresh, 1800 retry, 604800 expire, 86400 minimum TTL. However, given that domain.com is working for me, I take that www.domain.com should have as well at the same time

Comment: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/serial.html So, on top of having to wait 48 hours to make sure DNS worked, updating the serial number is this error prone. Ouch. Meanwhile, I have a website with more than 1000 users asking me when is it coming back online

Answer (score 0):

The servers telling the world where to go to find authoritative data for your domain are the servers for the *parent* domain of your domain. That is, if you want to change the IP addresses of the name servers for mydomain.com, you need to change those addresses *both* on your own servers and the servers for .com. The latter is typically done via an interface (usually web) provided by the people you pay to get the domain in the first place.

Apologies if this is too basic, but you don't mention changing your delegation anywhere in your question.

Comment: I was creating my own nameservers, so I wasn't using a web interface from my domain register. However, I decided to switch to their nameservers and set things up from there, because I wasn't being able to update it with my own zone files

Comment: What I was trying to say is that it's not a question of which servers are handling your domain, but there are some servers telling the rest of the world which servers are handling your domain. If you change which servers are handling your domain, you have to let those other servers know, or they will keep telling people to go ask the servers that used to handle your domain before.